# New portfolio items appearing smaller on the grid

Tags: images, thumbnails

For some reason that I cannot understand the new items that I'm adding to my portfolio are appearing smaller in the portfolio grid. I'm relatively new to this, so I'm completely lost. If it were something that affects all items I think I would have a better idea where to start looking for the problem, but in this case, I'm completely lost!
I would appreciate any general orientation of where to start looking for the problem. Here is a link to my portfolio where you can see the grid. I can share any code if needed, I just don't know which one to share :/

http://www.innerlightleaks.com/portfolio/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are your source images all of the same size ?

If you hover the src attribute for your images with the Chrome Developper Tools, it will tell you the natural size.

For the smaller images, the natural size is: 292 x 190, 400x260.
For the bigger images, the natural size is: 306x260 (all seem to have the same).

My best guess is that if you crop/fiddle with the size of your images, you might be able to get them at the right size.

Comment: Quite an obvious solution, but somehow I missed it. Thanks!!! I changed the size of one of the images and now it works. However, I remember that before I used to choose any image and automatically it was resized to the proper size... I guess is due to an update on the theme or something...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was causing the issue, but I was able to fix it using the [Simple Image Sizes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/) plugin which allowed me to resize the thumbnails of certain images to a specific size determined by me. 
I tried first another plugin that is more popular called [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) but that one regenerates all the thumbnails so I found it slower for what I needed